# Visualizar projeto - PHP

Tags: php, php-7, visual-studio-code, localhost

Estou iniciando na linguagem de PHP e gostaria de saber como eu faço para visualizar meu projeto, uma vez que ao utilizar o localhost o erro "404" aparece com a mensagem "Not Found".

O diretório do meu arquivo .php é esse:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\loja

O localhost que eu tento acessar é esse:

> http://localhost/loja/index.php

Estou fazendo algo de errado?

Comment: E o servidor Apache está ligado? Se sim, quais são os últimos registros no arquivo de log ?

Comment: 11:17:22  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:17:22  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:17:22  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

Comment: Olha se vc não está usando outro serviço que esteja usando a mesma porta que o Xampp, ou se vc não configurou alguma porta diferente da padrão... Olhando assim deveria estar funcionando, pelo visto o php e o apache estão rodando

Comment: Se vc estiver usando o Live-Serve do VS Code, deixe ele desligado enquanto vc faz o teste com o Xampp, não sei se pode ser isso, mas vale o teste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo erro que você postou nos comentários, percebo que o Apache não está iniciando devido à problemas com portas ou configurações. Se for o caso, reinstale por completo o seu Xampp, se mesmo assim o problema continuar, verifique a liberação das portas 80 e 443, tanto no seu Firewall como também eu seu roteador caso use. Se você usar um roteador entre o modem e o computador, tente ligar diretamente no modem principal da sua internet e veja se funciona, se funcionar é algum bloqueio por padrão no seu roteador.

Aguardo mais detalhes após estes procedimentos.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, o problema estava relacionado a porta, decidi acessar Xampp > Apache > Conf > httpd.conf, ao abrir o arquivo pelo bloco de notas mudei o Listen 80 para outro número de porta e funcionou. Para visualizar o projeto depois disso só precisei adicionar o :85 depois do local host, ficando assim:

> https://localhost:85/loja/index.php